# How to transfer an asset which isn't money from one party to another in corda

Tags: corda

Basically i have two parties in my state and i want to transfer an asset say a house or a car from one party to another or issue the same asset to a party so how can i manage that?

I tried searching the docs but couldn't find anything substantial

Comment: Are these assets your own FungibleStates or are you using the Token SDK?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about how should I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

If your modeling or defining your own states then you decide. Some attribute of your state is set to the owning party. Transfer of the asset is a transaction that changes the party on this attribute, presumably initiated by only the owner or a party delegated that power.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the example of your `House State`

Your house state might look something like this:

```html
@BelongsToContract(HouseContract::class)
data class HouseState (
        val address: String,
        val appraisal: Amount<USD>,
        val owner: Party,
        val participants: List<Party>,
        override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
): ContractState, LinearState {

    fun withNewOwner(party: Party): HouseState {
      return this.copy(owner = party)
    } 

    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() = players
    }


}
```

In Corda, states are immutable. You would change the owner of a House by marking the input state as consumed and issuing a new houseState onto the ledger with the owner field updated.

Some states even have convenience methods (see the HouseState above) That return a copy of the input state with a field updated (in this case the owner) to be included in the transaction as the output state.